# I need help with my ocean currents

Tags: science-based, earth-like, ocean, currents

I haven’t really ever gotten this far in worldbuilding, and I’m kinda stuck on ocean currents. My world has lots of tiny little islands that are on 2 slightly  submerged continents (around 3 metres below sea level): would the currents just act the same as if they weren’t submerged? Also, my planet has a 12-hour rotational period and is 0.87 percent earth’s size and mass everything else is the same.

I have change my atmospheric circulation so that it’s three cells per hemisphere and have also changed the currents accordingly (image below)[image]

I have finished the main ocean currents, but I still need help with the currents on the submerged continents. Is this alright?[image]

Image of Submerged Continents:[image]

Comment: Shallow water will definitely affect your current speeds, directions and temperatures. Can you highlight on the map or at least try describe roughly where your sunken continents are?

Comment: Good God! DoI read it the wrong way or do you really mean  the wind circulation change direction twice, West-East-West, over the span of about +/-5 degrees latitude around the ecuator? And those winds are supposed to be sorta permanent? Because, if the later, my mind shuts down thinking an the shallow mass of pretty warm water pumping heat in an atmosphere so prone to whirlwinds, the storms there should put the tornado alley to shame.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I took that to be a representation of the pretty standard equatorial and counter-equatorial currents. Ie doldrums.

Comment: Thanks for the map edits.

Comment: Not somethig you may want to read but...While the number of feasible atmospheric cells is not clearly stated anywhere in the literature I don't know if 2 cells per hemisphere would work. I recall reading something about Euclidean geometry and loops etc that allowed cell systems with groups of [1; 3;... don't recall rest of math sequence but fairly certain it's just odd numbers]. Apologies, I can't recall exactly what the search terms are either. It's to do with convergence/divergence number sequencing. As you've already noted: what do you do at the poles of your 2cell system!

Comment: @EveryBitHelps that’s annoying, I don’t want to have 1 cell per hemisphere, 3 cells is to earth like and anything more then 1-2x earths rotation has wayyyy to complicated cells. Is there anything in between like how many cells would a 36 hour day planet have?

Comment: @SN9 ahh finally hit on the right wording. Been bugging me all day! I was reading an article about Eulerian circuits and paths (and the [7 bridges of köningsberg problem](https://medium.com/basecs/k%C3%B6nigsberg-seven-small-bridges-one-giant-graph-problem-2275d1670a12)). The atmospheric circulation calculations/theories seem to work with coupled eulurain models. I'm not sure if we can describe non-eulurain circulation without writing an entire thesis and number of books!

Comment: Any ocean less than about 10 metres deep can be considered dry land, for ocean current calculation. Any ocean less than about 100 metres deep will greatly influence currents.

Comment: I think 3 cells and the same planet rotation direction can still provide plenty of difference from earth while still giving your brain a break and not having to solve huge theoretical atmospheric mathematical problems! Don't make life harder than it has to be unless you really into that sort of math!

Comment: This helped me a lot with my ocean currents: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=n_E9UShtyY8

Comment: @EveryBitHelps I’ve decided that my world will have a 12 hour rotation period so that i still have the same amount of cells as earth without being to much like earth

Comment: Could OP mark the continents outlines on a map? So we know which islands are parts of a continents.

Comment: If your world has a large moon, tidal effects in these large, shallow seas would significantly effect your currents. Some of them would become tidal flats at low tide. based on the size of the submerged continents, that could be huge areas of sea/land

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed sunken continents are what I marked with black dotted lines
I marked hot currents in red and cold in blue, as far as I understand they should behave

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm no oceanographer, but I would say that your submerged continents would affect ocean currents as if they weren't submerged. Surface currents generally run as deep a 400 meters, so it's entirely reasonable that your continents being around 3 meters below sea level would exert an effect on surface currents. Deep water currents would naturally be affected. Of course your sunken continents would still have currents flowing across them, possibly faster than your ocean currents, and possibly in bizarre directions depending on the topology. Take a look at the Gulf of Mexico Loop Current and the eddies it creates here: https://texaspelagics.com/gom-info/gom-loop/ for some ideas.
As far as your polar regions, wind currents are one of the primary drivers of ocean currents, so your polar currents would in all likelihood be eastward as well. This is of course assuming your world is NOT a rotating sphere in which there is a Coriolis effect to drive the wind and currents different directions as they do on Earth.

Comment: " assuming your world is NOT a rotating sphere" Huh? If it's not a rotating sphere, what is it - a planet with a day as long as an year?

Comment: Can you please elaborate further? I don’t really understand how it’ll work because the Gulf of Mexico only has one side open to sea but the submerged continents have all sides open to sea. How would it work with all sides open to sea?

Comment: @ SN9 Think of the Indonesian and neighbouring islands. That's a warm shallow sea open from East, West and South.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps I took some inspiration from the Indonesian ocean currents, and added a map with them on it. Do they look alright?